# Dúvida em lógica de array em JS

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer com que o array recebido da função **ACONTECE** (nessa função eu recebo os horários dos alunos que entraram cedo,atrasado e pontual.) vá para a função **ABERTURAS** (e aqui eu informo se a aula acontece ou nao, como mostra o enunciado abaixo), ou seja, quero puxar as informações recebidas em **ACONTECE**, isso é o que o exercício pede:

> Escreva as seguintes funções: **1. acontece**, que diz se a aula sucederá
>   de acordo com o array dos estudantes que entraram. **2. aberturas**, que
>   utiliza um array com os arrays dos estudantes que entraram nos outros
>   dias, e a quantidade mínima de estudantes, e diga quais os dias em que
>   as aulas aconteceram e quais não. Por exemplo:

```
aberturas([alunosDaSegunda, alunosDaTerça, alunosDaQuarta], 
[true, false, false]
```

Esse é o meu código feito até o momento, porém não sei se a lógica está correta, preciso de auxílio para entender.

```
function acontece(alunos){
  var alunosDaSegunda = []
  var alunosDaTerca = []
  var alunosDaQuarta = []
  for (var i = 0; i < alunos.lenght; i++){
    if(i <= 0){
      return alunos
    }else
      return 
  }
}

function aberturas(temAula){
  var alunosDaSegunda = []
  var alunosDaTerca = []
  var alunosDaQuarta = []
  for(var i = 0; i < temAula.lenght; i++ )
    if(temAula > 2 ){
      return temAula
    }else
      return

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que entender que quando você declara `return` em uma função, a sua execução é encerrada. Não adianta nada declarar um `for` e então retornar na primeira interação. `yield` tem um comportamento mais parecido com o que você está tentando fazer, mas não há necessidade de utiliza-lo nesse caso.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
function acontece(arrAlunos, qtdMinima) {
    var alunosPontuais = 0;
    for (var aluno of arrAlunos) {
        if (aluno <= 0)
            alunosPontuais++;
    }

    return alunosPontuais >= qtdMinima;
}

function aberturas(arrAlunosDias, qtdMinima){
    var arrDiasComAulas = [];
    for (var alunosDia of arrAlunosDias) {
        arrDiasComAulas.push(acontece(alunosDia, qtdMinima));
    }

    return arrDiasComAulas;
}

// 0 = aluno pontual, -1 = aluno adiantado, 1 = aluno atrasado
var arrDiasComAulas = aberturas(
    [
        [0, 0, 0],   //Dia 1
        [-1, 0, -1], //Dia 2
        [1, 1, 1]    //Dia 3
    ], 2 //Mínimo de alunos para contecer uma aula
);

console.log(arrDiasComAulas);
```

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pela explicação!!